# Even Odd rows without using an outer query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    c,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) ROWNUM,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) % 2 BOOL
FROM love
--WHERE BOOL = 1
```

I am trying to fetch the odd/even rows without using an outer query.

Using a generated column in the same query will not work, but is there a way to make it?

Comment: Well, too bad. Wrapping the query *is* the solution. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: What's wrong with the method you're currently using?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Was just wondering if there is another way that I am not aware of. Thanks for the info, I am already considering removing this question.

Comment: @MartinSmith Example?

Comment: Possible to get the odd ones anyway. Using `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. This will fail for even rows in the event that there are no even rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin's answer looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES a, b, c,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) as ROWNUM,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) % 2 as BOOL
FROM love
ORDER BY BOOL DESC;
```

This is very clever and I give full attribution to Martin.

I will note that for guaranteed correctness, this assumes that `a` is unique.  Sort in SQL (and SQL Server) are not stable.  So, if there are duplicate values, then the ordering could actuall be different for `rownum` and `bool`.